# The wisdom behind rajm of muhsan

Tags: fiqh, zina, rajm

I've been thinking recently a lot about the rajm of muhsan when he commits zina. And I don't get it, what's the wisdom behind it, I know we accept everything that Allah sent, but there's always a wisdom behind it, and that one, I quite can't get. So in order for rajm to take place there should be 4 witnesses or a confession. But since no-one will confess, the rajm doesn't happen almost. But in the times of the prophet (p.b.u.h), when he asked people who did it, they confessed and got killed. What's the wisdom behind it. Should a person who did this just hide it, and hope for the forgivness of Allah or what? And why is that a person who was married, who consumed marriage halal way, but not married at the moment is punished the same way as a cheater. For me, it looks like it's almost saying that "once you marry, you can't just have fun with other girls, so do it before you get married", but it's complete the opposite of the meaning of marriage, like the marriage is supposed to save people from doing zina, but what if person married, got divorced and doesn't have an opportunity to marry again, is it fair to punish him the same way as a cheater if he commits zina? I'm trying to find the wisdom here, someone help me please, with the links to the sources directly, not just words of the sheikhs.

Answer (score 0):

Let me present you with two scenarios:

- **Scenario 1**: A man has daughters, and someone commits zina with one of them.
- **Scenario 2**: A man has daughters, and he gives one of them in marriage to someone. Eventually, the marriage breaks off. Then, after the marriage is over because he cannot find another marriage, this ex-son-in-law commits zina with one of the man's daughters (even perhaps his ex-wife).

In which case would the father be more angry at this zani? It is obvious he would be more angry in the second case.

Why would he be more angry in the second case? Because the zani shows the highest level of ingratitude. The father already gave this man one of his daughters in marriage, then this man turns around and commits zina with one of them after all he has given him??

Now, how is it when Allah has much more gheerah and righteous anger over His female servants than any father can have over his daughter? ([Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1499a))

To give you another example, imagine a restaurant. The owner of the restaurant gives a man free food out of his love for him. Then, one day the man decides to steal food from him! He would be more angry at this man who has been given food than at some stranger who steals from him.

In summary, one wisdom for the punishment of stoning when the zani has been married before (and had intercourse) is that committing zina after someone has already been given legitimate and halal benefit of the same type is the height of disobedience and ingratitude.

That being said, the Quran and Sunnah do not explicitly state the reason behind these punishments.

And Allah knows best.